# Why wouldn't lspci show extended config space?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, pci-e

I use in different Linux distribution running on Windows 10-hosted VirtualBox the following command:

```
lspci -xxxx
```

It prints dump of config spaces up to 64 bytes

When I try

```
sudo lspci -xxxx
```

It prints dump of config spaces up to 256 bytes

Can I get whole PCIe 4096 config space using `lspci`?

Comment: will `lspci -vvvv -xxxx` help?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, no

Comment: Do the devices in question have a PCI Express capability (capability id 10h)?

Comment: @prl, Good Point. Some of devices show all zeros in PCI capabilities space. Let me check if others have PCI Express Capability...

Comment: @prl, Ok, you are right. Only one device has nonzero capabilities pointer. Even that device does not have PCI Express capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@prl made a good point to check if there is PCI Express capability (capability id 10h).

Turned out that most of devices seen under VirtualBox have all zeros in PCI capabilities space (0x40 thru 0xFF), they also have zero capabilities pointer. Even a device which has some capabilities does not have PCI Express capability.

I think it is VirtualBox emulation limitation.